# bootbox confirm: form not submitted on enter key press

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bootbox

I'm using bootbox to show a custom form to the user. Afterwards that form is used to modify the UI. Everything works fine, if I press the "Ok" button in the bootbox dialog. Pressing the ENTER button without touching the form (all values on default) also works properly. But if I put focus on one of my input fields and then press enter, my page just resets as if I pressed F5.
Can this be fixed?

My code:

```
bootbox.confirm({
        message: "<form id='newGameForm' action=''>\
    Playlist ID: <br> \
    <input type='text' name='playlistID' size='35'/><br>\
    Ruleset: <br>\
    <input type='radio' name='rules' value='classic' checked> Classic\ 
    <input type='radio' name='rules' value='adv'> Advanced\
    </form>",
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                let newGameParams = $('#newGameForm').serializeArray().reduce(function (obj, item) {
                    obj[item.name] = item.value;
                    return obj;
                }, {});
                initGame(newGameParams);
            }
        }
    });
```

Edit: I found out that pressing enter while focusing the form is circumventing the bootbox's submit and instead uses the form's own submit. This adds `?playlistID=ABC123&rules=classic` to the url and reloads the page. Can I somehow reroute the submit?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how the confirm helper is intended to be used - your use-case pretty much requires you to use the dialog helper. At a minimum, to make what you have *probably* work, you would need to capture the `onsubmit` event of the form you're inserting into the dialog.

Here's an example. I also moved your form out to a template script tag, since it makes the rest cleaner:

Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="form-template">
    <form id="newGameForm" action="">
        Playlist ID: <br>
        <input type="text" name="playlistID" size="35"><br>
        Ruleset: <br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rules" value="classic" checked> Classic</label> <br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rules" value="adv"> Advanced</label> <br>
    </form>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
var template = $('#form-template').html();

var $dialog = bootbox.confirm({
    message: template,
    callback: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            let newGameParams = $('#newGameForm').serializeArray().reduce(function (obj, item) {
                obj[item.name] = item.value;
                return obj;
            }, {});
            initGame(newGameParams);
        }
    }
});

$dialog.on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
    var $form = $('#newGameForm');

    $form.on('submit', functino(fe){
        fe.preventDefault();

        $dialog.find('.btn-primary').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

This only works if you do not override the btn class on the confirm button, but as-is, basically triggers a click on the confirm button when the embedded form is submitted. This example hooks into the form's submit event on the [shown.bs.modal](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#events) event (that link is for Bootstrap 4, but the same event is available in Bootstrap 3).